# Type can not be used to index type, when trying to type nested objects

Tags: typescript

Codesandbox for the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-hugle-3k15n?file=/src/index.ts

I have an object that holds data for images used in my app, something like this

```
const IMAGES = {
  backgrounds: {
    stone: {
      source: require('assets/stone.jpg'),
      width: 40,
      height: 50
    }
  },
  buttons: {
    green: {
      source: require('assets/green.jpg'),
      width: 20,
      height: 5
    }
  }
}
```

I then have a helper function that preloads these assets and stores them in a global state, this global state has following type definition (`Texture` type here is a special preloaded asset, I don't believe it is relevant to the issue)

```
interface ImagesState {
  backgrounds: Record<keyof typeof IMAGES['backgrounds'], Texture>;
  buttons: Record<keyof typeof IMAGES['buttons'], Texture>;
}
```

Finally, I am working on a function to preload the assets that at the moment looks like this

```
export async function preloadImages<C extends keyof ImagesState, A extends keyof ImagesState[C]>(
  category: C,
  names: A[]
) {

  names.forEach(name => console.log(IMAGES[category][name].source))

}
```

The idea of this function is to look like this `preloadImages('backgrounds', ['stone'])` and provide auto complete for first argument and then second one based on the first. Right now I am getting an error at `IMAGES[category][name]` saying following

> Type 'A' cannot be used to index type '{ backgrounds: {
> stone: ...

I could replace things like `C extends keyof ImagesState` to be `C extends keyof IMAGES` and it works, but this function needs these types to be inherited from state as it does further work with it latter on.

Comment: DId you ever find a solution to this?